# Cannot init Facebook Payment, "Account id missing"

Tags: facebook, facebook-payments

When I'm trying to init a payment from within my FB app, I get the error:

> API Error Code: 1383003
>   API Error Description: Account id missing.

Searching for this suggests that I need to link a company to the app. However, I've already done so. This company is in fact already being used for real payments in a different app I manage.

Is there something else that I need to do, or do I need to contact Facebook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've reported this [as a bug to Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/620035204723206/), and they've accepted it.

Comment: We are still seeing this issue - FB says its fixed - but we're still seeing it.